# custom header in laravel middleware return NULL

Tags: php, laravel, request, header, middleware

Currently I create custom header in ajax GET request to verify the header in the middleware as describe [here](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-and-check-custom-header-with-middleware-for-rest-api-in-laravel-5-example.html).

The problem is when I tried to print out the header value in middleware, it successfully display in ajax success callback but return NULL in print out command! Hence the header value is not captured in middleware class.

Here is the ajax code:

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');

$.ajax({                                                           
    type: "get",                                                  
    url: link,
    headers: { "custom-header": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" },
        success: function(result){
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
    }
});
```

Here is the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
        $token = $request->header('custom-header'); 
        die(var_dump($token));
}
```

First result from ajax success callback:
[image]

After alert pop-out closed:
NULL value printed on the screen!

I intend to capture the header value to do further verification. Tried to configured .htaccess file but I think not the problem with that.

Comment: "After alert pop-out closed: NULL value printed on the screen!" None of your code prints anything to the screen - not a null value, not the header either. Where is your "print out" command?

Comment: hi @ceejayoz, tried print_r($token) before die() but still only display on alert-popout but not in the screen. I just want to make sure the token is captured and store in variable.

Comment: Your PHP side of things is working just fine. As you can see in the `alert`, the data's there, and being output just fine. You've just got no code in the `success` function to *do* anything with that response (other than `alert()`ing). If you want the result of the AJAX call to show up on the page, **you have to write some code to do that**.